# Best Way to Build eLearning App

Tags: ajax, html, internet-explorer, audio

I'm building an eLearning app with roughly 20 scenes. They contain audio & synched text, have interactive sections and animation. It needs to be compatible with desktops and tablets.

My initial thinking was to build a Flash version and serve it to Internet Explorer to avoid general I.E. CSS issues. Then build an alternate HTML5 version for the major browsers and tablets.

Questions:

- How do I redirect to I.E. without the ActiveX warning messages? I'd like a clean redirect.
- Do I need to check for 64 bit I.E. that doesn't support Flash? If so, how?
- What's the best way to synch audio and text in HTML5? Or just accomplish this in a video?
- I'm using AJAX to load scenes into one shell. Is this a good idea?

I know this is alot. I'm not looking for huge answers, just hoping to be pointed in the right direction.

Here's what I'm using to redirect:

```
function msieversion() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer, return version number
 alert(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
else    // If another browser, return 0
 alert('otherbrowser');

return false;
```

}

Thanks,

E

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, a question should only contain one question...

Answer (score 0):

> 1. ...build a Flash version and serve it to Internet Explorer to avoid general I.E. CSS issues. Then build an alternate HTML5 version for the major browsers and tablets.

Building two versions (Flash and HTML5) is a really, really bad idea. It doubles your work and halves your pay. You should build a single HTML version that works across all browsers, it is not that hard today. Based on what you described and my years of experience with e-learning, your content will work in IE8+ and modern browsers easily. You will need a Flash fallback for HTML5 audio though (see below) in IE8.

> 1. How do I redirect to I.E. without the ActiveX warning messages?

Ask a separate question on SO. A good idea would be to do a server-side redirect before you even load HTML, if possible.

> 2. Do I need to check for 64 bit I.E. that doesn't support Flash? If so, how?

As far as I know, you can install Flash Player 11 on 64-bit Internet Explorer on Windows 7 (proof: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-64-bit-operating.html). Also, you should always check whether Flash is supported, not for specific browser, because there is a million ways how Flash can be disabled even in browsers that you presume are Flash-friendly. Finally, ask a separate question on SO.

> 3. What's the best way to sync audio and text in HTML5?

Use any HTML5 media player, there are tons of them. My favourite is mediaelement.js. It allows you to trigger JS events from the playhead (as in, "run function showThisOrThat() when the playhead reaches 01:22sec) regardless of whether the media is played through HTML5 or Flash.

If you need a scrubber (as in, learners can jump to any point in the media file and the slide should jump to that state as well), I suggest you look into GSAP as well.

> 4. I'm using AJAX to load scenes into one shell. Is this a good idea?

This is the sort of question that gets banned on SO, so allow me just ignore it.